# Как вычислить среднее значение?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Модель `book` связана с `user` через `rate`(с полем rating).

Хочу сделать так, чтобы при создании нового 'rate' пересчитывалось среднее значение для книги и записывалось в "книжное" поле `av_rating`. Пробовал так:

```
def create
  @new_rate = @book.rates.build(rate_params)
  @new_rate.user = current_user

if @new_rate.save
  @book.av_rating = Rate.where(book_id: @book.id).average(:rating)
  redirect_to @book
else
 ...
```

Поле остается пустым

Comment: а где ты сохраняешь вот это `@book.av_rating` после save?

Comment: `@book`-то тоже надо сохранять, если изменили.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так как вы присваиваете значение атрибута для объекта находящегося в памяти, в базу данных значение не попадает и не сохраняется. В качестве альтернативы уже упоминавшемуся явному вызову метода `save` модели, можно воспользоваться методом `update`, который приводит к явному сохранению нового значения в базу данных

```
def create
  @new_rate = @book.rates.build(rate_params)
  @new_rate.user = current_user

  if @new_rate.save
    @book.update(av_rating: Rate.where(book_id: @book.id).average(:rating))
    redirect_to @book
  else
  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

С этого куска кода видно что ты меняешь рейтинг но не делаешь сохранение в базу данных.
В это случаи нужно просто сделать еще один сейв для объекта `@book`

```
if @new_rate.save
  @book.av_rating = Rate.where(book_id: @book.id).average(:rating)
  @book.save
  redirect_to @book
else
```